# Auto color Japanese characters

Tags: vba, ms-word

I wrote a macro to detect Japanese font in the document, then make its color red while making the English text blue.

It works except for number characters like 0123456789. The numbers are not treated as Japanese but English, so the numbers are still blue, not red as I expected.

```
Sub Replace_font_color()   
    Dim kage As Range
    Dim taro As Document

    Set taro = ActiveDocument     

    With taro
        For Each kage In .Words
            kage.Font.Name = "MS Mincho"
            'Replace all text by MS Mincho Font

            kage.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
            'Replace all text font by Times New Roman font
            'Since Japanese characters can't be replaced by non Japanese font
            'so the Japanese characters remain in MS Minchon font

            If kage.Font.Name = "MS Mincho" Then
                kage.Font.Name = "MS Mincho"
                kage.Font.Size = 10.5
                kage.Font.Color = vbRed
            End If

            If kage.Font.Name = "Times New Roman" Then
                kage.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
                kage.Font.Size = 13
                kage.Font.Color = vbBlue
            End If
        Next
    End With    
End Sub
```

Before executing Macro
[image: Before executing Macro]

After executing Macro
[image: After executing Macro]

Comment: You already say *"Since Japanese characters can't be replaced by non Japanese font so the Japanese characters remain in MS Minchon font."* which means numbers **can** be replaced by non Japanese font and therefore will be logically formatted as blue. • An idea could be to check if a word [is numeric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isnumeric-function) and then check if the word left and right of it is Japanese if so format the number Japanese/red too. • Give it a try.

Comment: Numbers don't need a language, but I can see why you *think* they should. If the text is always split into entire paragraphs as your example, immediately color the entire paragraph and skip to the next one.